# how to find missing library dependency(or root cause) in static library and when cmake target is built using externalproject method

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, static-linking, missing-symbols

I want to use **static target** for jaeger instead of linking to a dynamic target,
static target compiles fine but when I use it in my codebase, I see **undefined reference errors**:
tried:

1. dynamic/static linking for thrift explicitly to ceph(primary codebase):

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/ceph-osd
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException::TTransportException(apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException::TTransportExceptionType, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionC2ENS2_23TTransportExceptionTypeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionC5ENS2_23TTransportExceptionTypeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x2d): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException::~TTransportException()':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionD2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport19TTransportExceptionD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransport::open()':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport4openEv[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport4openEv]+0x8b): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransport::close()':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport5closeEv[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport5closeEv]+0x8b): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransport::read_virt(unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport9read_virtEPhj[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport9read_virtEPhj]+0x92): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransport::write_virt(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport10write_virtEPKhj[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport10write_virtEPKhj]+0x92): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TTransport::consume_virt(unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport12consume_virtEj[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport10TTransport12consume_virtEj]+0x8e): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol::TProtocol(std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol9TProtocolC2ESt10shared_ptrINS0_9transport10TTransportEE[_ZN6apache6thrift8protocol9TProtocolC5ESt10shared_ptrINS0_9transport10TTransportEE]+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory::TProtocolFactory()':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TProtocolFactoryC2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift8protocol16TProtocolFactoryC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TBufferBase::consume(unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport11TBufferBase7consumeEj[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport11TBufferBase7consumeEj]+0xe4): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer::TMemoryBuffer(unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TMemoryBufferC2Ej[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TMemoryBufferC5Ej]+0x23): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `unsigned int apache::thrift::transport::readAll<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>(apache::thrift::transport::TTransport&, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport7readAllINS1_10TTransportEEEjRT_Phj[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport7readAllINS1_10TTransportEEEjRT_Phj]+0xd6): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `unsigned int apache::thrift::transport::readAll<apache::thrift::transport::TBufferBase>(apache::thrift::transport::TBufferBase&, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport7readAllINS1_11TBufferBaseEEEjRT_Phj[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport7readAllINS1_11TBufferBaseEEEjRT_Phj]+0xd6): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::protocol::TCompactProtocolFactoryT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>::~TCompactProtocolFactoryT()':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol24TCompactProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportEED2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift8protocol24TCompactProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory::~TProtocolFactory()'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6apache6thrift8protocol17TProtocolDefaultsE[_ZTVN6apache6thrift8protocol17TProtocolDefaultsE]+0x170): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol::skip_virt(apache::thrift::protocol::TType)'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6apache6thrift8protocol24TCompactProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportEEE[_ZTIN6apache6thrift8protocol24TCompactProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6apache6thrift8protocol17TProtocolDefaultsE[_ZTIN6apache6thrift8protocol17TProtocolDefaultsE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(UDPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolDefaults::~TProtocolDefaults()':
UDPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol17TProtocolDefaultsD2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift8protocol17TProtocolDefaultsD5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol::~TProtocol()'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(HTTPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `jaegertracing::utils::HTTPTransporter::HTTPTransporter(jaegertracing::net::URI const&, int)':
HTTPTransporter.cpp:(.text+0x19f): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::transport::THttpClient::THttpClient(std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(HTTPTransporter.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::protocol::TBinaryProtocolFactoryT<apache::thrift::transport::TTransport, apache::thrift::protocol::TNetworkBigEndian>::~TBinaryProtocolFactoryT()':
HTTPTransporter.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift8protocol23TBinaryProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportENS1_17TNetworkBigEndianEED2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift8protocol23TBinaryProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportENS1_17TNetworkBigEndianEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory::~TProtocolFactory()'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(HTTPTransporter.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6apache6thrift8protocol23TBinaryProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportENS1_17TNetworkBigEndianEEE[_ZTIN6apache6thrift8protocol23TBinaryProtocolFactoryTINS0_9transport10TTransportENS1_17TNetworkBigEndianEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(ThriftSender.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer::TMemoryBuffer()':
ThriftSender.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TMemoryBufferC2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TMemoryBufferC5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(Agent.cpp.o): in function `jaegertracing::agent::thrift::AgentProcessor::dispatchCall(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, void*)':
Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1037): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TApplicationException::write(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(Agent.cpp.o): in function `jaegertracing::agent::thrift::AgentConcurrentClient::send_emitZipkinBatch(std::vector<twitter::zipkin::thrift::Span, std::allocator<twitter::zipkin::thrift::Span> > const&)':
Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1b32): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::TConcurrentSendSentry(apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentClientSyncInfo*)'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1c63): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::commit()'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1c7b): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::~TConcurrentSendSentry()'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1d04): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::~TConcurrentSendSentry()'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(Agent.cpp.o): in function `jaegertracing::agent::thrift::AgentConcurrentClient::send_emitBatch(jaegertracing::thrift::Batch const&)':
Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1da4): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::TConcurrentSendSentry(apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentClientSyncInfo*)'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1ed5): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::commit()'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1eed): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::~TConcurrentSendSentry()'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text+0x1f76): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::async::TConcurrentSendSentry::~TConcurrentSendSentry()'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(Agent.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::TDispatchProcessor::process(std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>, std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>, void*)':
Agent.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift18TDispatchProcessor7processESt10shared_ptrINS0_8protocol9TProtocolEES5_Pv[_ZN6apache6thrift18TDispatchProcessor7processESt10shared_ptrINS0_8protocol9TProtocolEES5_Pv]+0x7e): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::GlobalOutput'
/usr/bin/ld: Agent.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift18TDispatchProcessor7processESt10shared_ptrINS0_8protocol9TProtocolEES5_Pv[_ZN6apache6thrift18TDispatchProcessor7processESt10shared_ptrINS0_8protocol9TProtocolEES5_Pv]+0x8b): undefined reference to `apache::thrift::TOutput::printf(char const*, ...)'
/usr/bin/ld: jaeger/lib/libjaegertracing.a(Agent.cpp.o): in function `apache::thrift::concurrency::Mutex::~Mutex()':
Agent.cpp:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift11concurrency5MutexD2Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift11concurrency5MutexD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::concurrency::Mutex'
```

2. tried changing the order of thrift static library linking.
3. HINT: the **static target created by Project's CMake works fine** with example code, but I don't know how to test that target when it has been built as ExternalProject(CMake), can I in some way do this?

on `using **nm -uC libjaegertracing.a**` gives **hint for missing definitions**, but I don't know why it is not getting included in the static file, while when I link to static target for example code(standalone) not with code I want to link it with, everything works fine.
I want to know how can I know and include missing library/definition so that I don't get these errors while trying to use a manually created target with libjaegertracing.a

```
U jaegertracing::thrift::Tag::Tag(jaegertracing::thrift::Tag const&)
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Tag::~Tag()
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Span::Span(jaegertracing::thrift::Span const&)
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Span::~Span()
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Batch::__set_spans(std::vector<jaegertracing::thrift::Span, std::allocator<jaegertracing::thrift::Span> > const&)
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Batch::__set_process(jaegertracing::thrift::Process const&)
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Batch::~Batch()
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Process::__set_tags(std::vector<jaegertracing::thrift::Tag, std::allocator<jaegertracing::thrift::Tag> > const&)
                 U jaegertracing::thrift::Process::~Process()
                 U jaegertracing::Tag::thrift(jaegertracing::thrift::Tag&) const
                 U jaegertracing::Span::thrift(jaegertracing::thrift::Span&) const
                 U std::runtime_error::what() const
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::empty() const
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const
                 U std::allocator<char>::allocator()
                 U std::allocator<char>::~allocator()
                 U std::ostream::operator<<(int)
                 U std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
                 U std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
                 U std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()
                 U std::exception::~exception()
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
```

also to verify whether I had the dependency library compiled to build static library, I used:

```
$ ar t libjaegertracing.a
```

which gave the complied files as expected:

```
Config.cpp.o
DynamicLoad.cpp.o
LogRecord.cpp.o
Logging.cpp.o
Reference.cpp.o
Span.cpp.o
SpanContext.cpp.o
Tag.cpp.o
TraceID.cpp.o
Tracer.cpp.o
TracerFactory.cpp.o
Sender.cpp.o
ThriftSender.cpp.o
BaggageSetter.cpp.o
RemoteRestrictionJSON.cpp.o
RemoteRestrictionManager.cpp.o
Restriction.cpp.o
RestrictionManager.cpp.o
RestrictionsConfig.cpp.o
Counter.cpp.o
Gauge.cpp.o
InMemoryStatsReporter.cpp.o
Metric.cpp.o
Metrics.cpp.o
NullCounter.cpp.o
NullGauge.cpp.o
NullStatsFactory.cpp.o
NullStatsReporter.cpp.o
NullTimer.cpp.o
StatsFactory.cpp.o
StatsFactoryImpl.cpp.o
StatsReporter.cpp.o
Timer.cpp.o
IPAddress.cpp.o
Socket.cpp.o
URI.cpp.o
Error.cpp.o
Header.cpp.o
Method.cpp.o
Request.cpp.o
Response.cpp.o
Endian.cpp.o
Hostname.cpp.o
Extractor.cpp.o
HeadersConfig.cpp.o
Injector.cpp.o
Propagator.cpp.o
CompositeReporter.cpp.o
Config.cpp.o
InMemoryReporter.cpp.o
LoggingReporter.cpp.o
NullReporter.cpp.o
RemoteReporter.cpp.o
Reporter.cpp.o
AdaptiveSampler.cpp.o
Config.cpp.o
ConstSampler.cpp.o
GuaranteedThroughputProbabilisticSampler.cpp.o
ProbabilisticSampler.cpp.o
RateLimitingSampler.cpp.o
RemoteSamplingJSON.cpp.o
RemotelyControlledSampler.cpp.o
Sampler.cpp.o
SamplingStatus.cpp.o
Agent.cpp.o
AggregationValidator.cpp.o
BaggageRestrictionManager.cpp.o
Collector.cpp.o
Dependency.cpp.o
SamplingManager.cpp.o
ZipkinCollector.cpp.o
agent_constants.cpp.o
agent_types.cpp.o
aggregation_validator_constants.cpp.o
aggregation_validator_types.cpp.o
baggage_constants.cpp.o
baggage_types.cpp.o
dependency_constants.cpp.o
dependency_types.cpp.o
jaeger_constants.cpp.o
jaeger_types.cpp.o
sampling_constants.cpp.o
sampling_types.cpp.o
zipkincore_constants.cpp.o
zipkincore_types.cpp.o
ErrorUtil.cpp.o
HexParsing.cpp.o
EnvVariable.cpp.o
RateLimiter.cpp.o
UDPTransporter.cpp.o
HTTPTransporter.cpp.o
YAML.cpp.o
ThriftMethods.cpp.o
```

target that builds fine: [works]
for adding dependency:

```
function(add_lib_deps lib)
  target_include_directories(${lib} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src>)
  target_link_libraries(${lib} PUBLIC ${link_flags} ${LIBS})
  target_compile_options(${lib} PUBLIC ${cxx_flags})
endfunction()
```

for adding source files:

```
add_library(jaegertracing-static STATIC ${SRC})
```

linking with example code:

```
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC ${JAEGERTRACING_LIB})
```

**with source code** [ where it doesn't work]

```
 add_library(jaeger-static STATIC IMPORTED)                                                                          
  add_dependencies(jaeger-static jaeger)                                                                              
  set(jaeger_INCLUDE_DIR ${jaeger_SOURCE_DIR}/src/)                                                                   
  set(jaeger_LIBRARY ${jaeger_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libjaegertracing.a)                                                     
  include_directories(jaeger_INCLUDE_DIR)                                                                             
  set_target_properties(jaeger-static PROPERTIES                                                                      
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "${jaeger_LIBRARY}"                                                                      
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES "CXX"                                                                           
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${jaeger_LIBRARY}"                                                                             
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${jaeger_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

then:

```
target_link_libraries() with primary target from my codebase
```

Comment: "but I don't know why it is not getting included in static file, while when I link to static target for example code" - When created, a **static library** is NOT linked with anything. So, if you want to link your application with that static library, you need also to link your application with its dependent libraries. There are a lot of information on this topic in the net and particularly on the Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes, while the static library is being created, it is linked with it's dependencies as well, that in this case also includes thrift, and it works fine when I run it with example code, but when I use the same library in code I want to link, I see the following errors, the question being: 1. why different nature when linking externally

Comment: "yes, while the static library is being created, it is linked with it's dependencies as well" - Once again, when a static library is created, it is **NOT linked** with anything. Whatever library you pass to `target_link_libraries`, it is not passed to the linker when create a static library. Creation of a static library doesn't involve linking step at all.

Comment: Didn't figure the root case of you problem, but you can try to use "nm" to print the symbol to check whether the symbol is really missing, as my experience, when linking multiple static libs, not only libs order matters, but some times you have to use -lA -lB -lA -lB to deal with cross reference problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, the same library I can get that working with example code, but not the codebase, it is not inconsistent behaviour, as when I check with `nm` I see the same definitions undefined in each version. So, I suspect the target behaviour difference > hence I want to use static target altogether in the codebase, instead of creating a new target, does this approach makes sense?

Comment: "I want to use static target altogether in the codebase, instead of creating a new target, does this approach makes sense?" - I could hardly imagine what do you mean by that. Could you add to the **question post** some **code**, which explains usage of the library in the "example" (where it works) and in the "codebase" (where it doesn't work)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev edited

Comment: When you create the library with `add_library(jaegertracing-static STATIC ${SRC})` you probably link it with some libraries, like `target_link_libraries(jaegertracing-static PUBLIC thrift)`. While this linkage doesn't become part of `libjaegertracing.a` **file**, it is automatically propagated to any executable which links with `jaegertracing-static` **target**. When create IMPORTED target, you need to link it with the same libraries but with INTERFACE keyword: `target_link_libraries(jaegertracing-static INTERFACE thrift)`. That way you "primary target" will also be linked with `thrift`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you motivate me to live! ;-) JK, thanks! this is one of my intial questions on stackoverflow, I know they are not the best formatted one, but having people like is great! thanks issue solved! :)

Comment: thanks you @ravenisadesk